# D3.stratify Uncaught Error: ambiguous: Distributive property

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to create a collapsible tree as per [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd). I have data containing around 350,000 rows. I converted the data to a JSON file and when I tested the script using a few rows, everything works exactly as it should.

But if I use the whole file, I get the error:
**Uncaught Error: ambiguous: Distributive property** at the line which stratifies the input data and forms a hierarchy.
My code is very similar to the example, but I'm reading from a JSON file whereas the example assigns the array of objects to a variable. I've given the code snippet below.

```
d3.json("fields_of_study_with_names.json", function(error, inputdata) {
  if (error) throw error;  
  console.log(inputdata);
  var treeData = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { return d.child; })
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
    (inputdata);

 // assign the name to each node
treeData.each(function(d) {
    d.name = d.data.child;
  });
  ...
```

I did some preprocessing and removed rows containing NaNs and duplicate rows (I thought the duplicate rows were causing this error). I can see the code works fine (as I checked with a smaller file), so it's clearly a problem with the input data. But I don't understand what the error says. 
Can someone help me?

PS: My data, after preprocessing, is something like this. The hierarchy is made up of 6 levels and the top level is 'root'.

```
[
{
    "child": "root",
    "parent": ""
},
{
    "child": "Geology",
    "parent": "root"
},
{
    "child": "Art",
    "parent": "root"
},
...
]
```

Comment: slowly modify (binary search) the size of the dataset to find the record that is the cause of the error. Where in the d3 source code is the error, use the non-min version.

Comment: Hi @rioV8. The error is in this line, in stratify: var treeData = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { return d.child; })
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
    (inputdata);       The reason that I haven't been able to modify the dataset too much to get the cause of the error is that it produces nodes without parents. There are 350,000 rows, so it's a bit difficult to find exactly which line is causing the error.

Comment: just cutting down your input has nothing to do with what you do with the data to generate svg stuff. I don't want your code line that has the error, what is needed is the full stack trace you can find in the console. Mark has already pointed you to a possible problem, so in your result data you have multiple sources for the same target, that needs a complete different data structure

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the `d3` [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/9f24171a29b544b9c68f180f7b589c418b304129/src/stratify.js#L48), I believe your problem to be that you have non-unique `child` in your data.  From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#stratify_id), the `.id` must return something unique:

> The returned string is then used to identify the node’s relationships in conjunction with the parent id. For leaf nodes, the id may be undefined; otherwise, the id must be unique. (Null and the empty string are equivalent to undefined.)

Further, the error is telling you that your non-unique id is the value `Distributive property`.

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

To @rioV8's point I would modify the code as:

```
var counts = {};
var treeData = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { 
        if (!counts[d.child]){
            counts[d.child] = 1;
            return d.child;
        } else {
            return d.child + " " + ++counts[d.child];
        }
     })
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
    (inputdata);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me understand the error. I didn't think for a moment that 'Distributive property' is a value in my input file, I thought it was an error description. But, this is a very common case in my data -- a node can have multiple parents. For example, I drew a section of my graph here: https://imgur.com/a/dTEkthG . How do you suggest I handle this case (the only thing I can think of is changing the name of all the duplicate child ids, but there must be 1000s of such cases in my input)?

Comment: @ash: I don't see multiple parents in your example image

Comment: @rioV8. It is effectively multiple parents. 'Distributive property' in my image has 2 parents 'Algebra' and 'Discrete mathematics'. The only way to encode multiple parents in D3 seems to be by having 2 copies of the 'Discrete mathematics' node, one under each parent. But the issue now is that 'De Morgan Algebra' and 'Distributivity', which both have 'Distributive property' as their parent, don't know which copy of 'Distributive property' they're the children of, i.e., whether they should attach to the one under 'Algebra' or the one under 'Discrete Mathematics', and there's an ambiguity error.

Comment: @ash Now I see the duplication - just use a different field to name the node and just generate numeric id's that are unique `id001234`